# Python http.server as a Windows service fails (error 1053)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a simple web server with Python. It works fine when I run with below command.

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

But when I make a Windows service with same code, it fails with error 1053.

```
sc create TestWebServer binPath="C:\Python37\python.exe -m http.server 8000" start=auto
```

I found that some relative posts say `debug` can solve this problem, but it doesn't work for me.

```
sc create TestWebServer binPath="C:\Python37\python.exe -m http.server 8000 debug" start=auto
```

**Edited**

I made a python code like below.

```
import os
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

os.chdir('.')
server = HTTPServer(server_address=('', 8000),
    RequestHandlerClass=CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

And I made it as Windows service, but it still fails with error 1053.

```
sc create TestWebServer binPath="C:\Python37\python.exe C:\TestWebServer.py" start=auto
```

Comment: Where did you read that this was possible?  The `http.server` module is not set up to be a Windows service.  It doesn't have the necessary service loop.  You can MAKE one, but the stock module can't do it.

Comment: Also, you don't have any idea what directory that command is running in.  You don't want it serving files from just anywhere.

Comment: @TimRoberts I edited my question. I made it as a python code and did same thing, but it still fails.

Comment: That is no different.  `os.chdir('.')` does nothing, and you still don't know what directory it will be in.  But more importantly, it's still not a Windows service.  A Windows service has to have a very specific format and a message loop, like a Windows application.  You can't just take a command line app and run it as a service.  http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/